# Pandas: replace value by current value concat a string

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
A
---
John
Matt
Annie
```

I want to get each value, concat with another string, and then put it back. Here is my expected output:

```
A
---
JohnAAA
MattAAA
AnnieAAA
```

How can I do this? And is there a pythonic way to do with multiple rows as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just concat strings:

```
df[“A”] = df[“A”]+”AAA”
```

One the major advantages of pandas is you can perform operation on arrays (just like numpy)..